# Angular lifecycle hook

Tags: angular, hook, lifecycle

When I use the firebase js sdk and make an angular project and implements the lifecycle hooks (for example afterviewinit) and write something on the console, the console message repeat again for infinity time. I would like that the message only once will be appeared on console.

Thanks the resolve for this problem

```
AppModule {
    constructor(){
        firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase);
    }
}

import { Component, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from ...;
@Component({
    selector: 'app-navbar',
    templateUrl: './navbar.component.html'
})
export class NavbarComponent implements DoCheck { 
    public isCollapsed = true; 
    isLoggedIn = false; 

    constructor(public userService: UserService) {}  

    ngDoCheck(){ console.log("navbar docheck"); } 
}
```

Comment: Please post the code that causes your problem.

Comment: The error is in the line 15 ;), 
without posting your code how you are expect to get some help ?!

Comment: I connect to firebase database with firebase js sdk :
export class AppModule {
  constructor(){
    firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase);
  }
}
I load the application , I make a console log message (console.log('text')) in a lifecycle hook function. And the message reloaded again, reloaded again. This is my problem. I would like to the message only once see if I do nothing in application (only type the url and load it),

Comment: A part of my code
import {Component, DoCheck, AfterViewChecked, AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';

…..
@Component({
 …..
})
export class NavbarComponent implements DoCheck, AfterViewChecked, AfterViewInit {
  
  constructor(
    public userService: UserService,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
    ) {
      this.userService.isLoggedIn$.subscribe(
        isLoggedIn => {
          this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn;
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
        }
      )
  }

  ngDoCheck(){
    console.log("navbar docheck");
  }

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you, you have put a `console.log()` in all the lifecycle-hooks.

If you have also done it in `ngAfterContentChecked` / `ngAfterViewChecked`, you have to keep in mind that it is executed constantly, every time the change detection is run (application state change) and if you have a `console.log()`, it will appear infinitely

ngDoCheck is a callback method that performs change-detection, invoked after the default change-detector runs, and again, every time the change detection is run (application state change), if you have a console.log(), it will appear infinitely.
If you want it to only run once, use ngOnInit, ngAfterContentInit or ngAfterViewInit

[angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Comment: And is it normally that I do not nothing (only I load the application and nothing else)  and on the console (dev tool bar) the message repeat constantly (not only once) ?

Comment: A comment : I see this problem every lifecycle hook. For example docheck too.

Comment: can you put your code (well formatted and readable) in the description of the question?

Comment: this is my connect to firebase
export class AppModule {
  constructor(){
    firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase);
  }
}

and this my component typescript file
import {Component, DoCheck} from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from ...;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html'
})
export class NavbarComponent implements DoCheck {
  public isCollapsed = true;
  isLoggedIn = false;

  constructor(
    public userService: UserService
    ) {
 }
      )
  }

  ngDoCheck(){
    console.log("navbar docheck");
  }

}

Comment: Nothing extra in my code, I use the firebase.initializeApp function in app.module.ts and use the life cycle hook function in one component and reloaded the console message every second while I do nothing.

Comment: I can not write the code prettier . Stackoverflow say me a character max length. I am a new user here.

Comment: ngDoCheck is a callback method that performs change-detection, invoked after the default change-detector runs, and again, every time the change detection is run (application state change) and if you have a console.log(), it will appear infinitely, If you want it to only run once, use ngOnInit, ngAfterContentInit or ngAfterViewInit https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: Daniel But I have seen an online curse and the checked  (doCheck, AfterviewChecked) filecycle hooks run only once.